# How to eager loading for belongsTo relationship on pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I have pivot table with below designed fields.

```
role_id  |   module_id  |   task_id
   1            1              1
   1            1              2
   1            1              3
```

This is my relation on Role model.

```
class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function modules(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class,'role_module_tasks','role_id','module_id')
                    ->withPivot(['task_id'])
                    ->using(RoleModuleTask::class);
    }
}
```

And another belongsTo relation on RoleModuleTask model (Pivot table).

```
class RoleModuleTask extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function task(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Task::class,'task_id');
    }
}
```

I try to call query as below.

```
@foreach (something()->modules as $module)
   Module:{{$module->name}} (Task:{{$module->pivot->task->name}} <br>
@endforeach
```

Then, I check query statement with laravel debug bar and got more than hundred queries as below.

```
    select * from `tasks` where `tasks`.`id` = 1 limit 1
    select * from `tasks` where `tasks`.`id` = 2 limit 1
    select * from `tasks` where `tasks`.`id` = 3 limit 1

.... so on
```

I would like to do eager loading for belongsTo relationship. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading) wherever you are initializing `Role`'s

```php
Role::with('modules.task')
```

This will eager load both a `Role`'s modules relationship and its nested task relationship.

Comment: Dear guyg, thank but I need to call from pivot instead.